# how to find out JBoss AS 7 version?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, java-7

I was able to use `standalone.bat --version` to get JBoss7 version from the command prompt; however, when integrate with installer, JBoss always crashes.

Earlier in **JBoss 4.x**, I was able to find JBoss version via

```
java -cp %JBOSS_HOME%/run.jar --version
```

(something like that).

I am wondering if there is similar way to find out **JBoss 7.x** version?

spec: JBoss AS 7.1.2, JDK1.7.0_02

Answer (score 1):

Try `%JBOSS_HOME%\standalone.bat --version`. That seems to work for me.

Comment: %JBoss_HOME%\standalone.bat --version crashed my installer jvm hence not helping in this case. I am wondering if there are other ways of getting the version.

Comment: What installer are you using? I'm not aware of one for 7.1.2.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting it on CVS, but the source is on GitHub https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as. I just tested it on Windows with no issues.